# Why can I use the "[ColumnName] As [DifferentColumnName]" SQL construct in MS Access but not from ASP.NET?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, android-sqlite, oledbcommand

Because SQLite requires a default "id" primary key column, I wanted to change this SQL:

```
SELECT t_omd.omd_id, t_omd.name, t_omd.amount, 
t_cjb.id, t_cjb.department, t_cjb.subdepartment, t_cjb.unit_cost, t_cjb.unit_list 
FROM t_omd 
LEFT JOIN t_cjb ON t_omd.cjb_id = t_cjb.id
ORDER BY t_omd.omd_id
```

to:

```
SELECT t_omd.omd_id, t_omd.name, t_omd.amount, 
t_cjb.id as redemptionid, t_cjb.department, t_cjb.subdepartment, t_cjb.unit_cost, t_cjb.unit_list 
FROM t_omd 
LEFT JOIN t_cjb ON t_omd.cjb_id = t_cjb.id
ORDER BY t_omd.omd_id
```

(changing "t_cjb.id" to "t_cjb.id as redemptionid" so that there wouldn't be two columns named "id" in the SQLite table - the SQLite-provided/demanded one, and this one in t_cjb)

The latter query works in MS Access (it returns records). However, although the former (sans "As") works in OleDb, the latter (with the "As" construct) does not.

Here is the OleDb code (in an ASP.NET / Web API app):

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Column named "id" interferes with required primary key Android 
           column name of the same name, so trying "as redemptionid" here
        // Returned 0 records
        //  cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT t_omd.omd_id, t_omd.name, t_omd.amount, 
        //  t_cjb.id as redemptionid, t_cjb.department, t_cjb.subdepartment, 
            t_cjb.unit_cost, t_cjb.unit_list 
        //  FROM t_omd 
        //  LEFT JOIN t_cjb ON t_omd.cjb_id = t_cjb.id
        //  ORDER BY t_omd.omd_id";
    // The SQL below works fine:
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT t_omd.omd_id, t_omd.name, t_omd.amount, 
         t_cjb.id, t_cjb.department, t_cjb.subdepartment,  
         t_cjb.unit_cost, t_cjb.unit_list 
         FROM t_omd 
         LEFT JOIN t_cjb ON t_omd.cjb_id = t_cjb.id
         ORDER BY t_omd.omd_id";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbDataReader oleDbD8aReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

Why does "real" SQL not recognize the "As" construct, whereas Access does?

Comment: What is the error message triggered by the statement which includes "as redemptionid"?

Comment: There is no err msg, it just returned 0 records instead of the 11 that it should (and does with the "sans As" version)... as to your moniker, it almost makes me think of "...reach for the sky"<= Rory Gallagher

Comment: Sorry then, I can't explain why it returns zero rows when the other version returns 11.  Since it's a static statement, try saving it in Access as something like *qryTest*.  Then in your ASP.Net, see how many rows you get when you substitute this statement: `SELECT * FROM qryTest;`

Comment: Both Access SQL and SQLite support the `SELECT columnName AS aliasName` construct so there must be something else going on in your code that is causing the problem. We can't trust the accuracy of your sample code because it won't even compile (due to missing `//` comment prefixes on a couple of the lines), so any attempts to answer your question would merely be guesses.